# unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. Chrome isn't opening in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've created a EC2 instance with installed ububtu. I've installed python3-pip and selenium webdriver and other requirements to run selenium on it.

I'm using this code but it raises this error.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://hagadmansa.com")
driver.set_window_size(1300, 500)
driver.save_screenshot("a.png")
driver.quit()
print("Done")
```

I'm using this code to take a screenshot of a particular website but it raises this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//home/ubuntu/chrome.py", line 10, in <module> 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall the selenium package from the terminal and again reinstall it also use python version 3.9 or 3.8 as 3.10 is not a stable version to use for development.